# How to change a color of the WinForm?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm working on WinForms project.
I need to change color of my form from white to black.

VB Code:

```
Dim g As Graphics, Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 

g= Me.CreateGraphics 

End Sub
```

Any Idea how can I do this with help of **g** instance's methods?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yysstebh.aspx)

Comment: Couldn't you just do `Me.BackColor = Color.Black`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as that...

```
 g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.Black), MyBase.ClientRectangle)
```

Comment: This seems like a strange way to just swap background colors. edit - Ninja edit got me!

Answer (score 2):

Set form1.backColor or something like that to your color of choice

Form1.backColor = Color.Black